# Is there a reason why Mathematica can't calculate this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

OK, so I realise that this is an integral I could never possibly calculate by hand (and I probably don't even know the relevant rules for), but the code

```
Assuming[
   Element[k, Integers] && k >= 1 && k <= n && Element[n, Integers] 
   && n > 1 && Element[j, Integers] && j >= 1 && j <= n &&
   Element[\[Alpha], Integers] && \[Alpha] >= 1, 
     Integrate[
       (k*n*u^(-1 + \[Alpha])*\[Alpha])/
       (1 + 4^\[Alpha]*(n - n*u)^(2*\[Alpha])),
     {u, k, k + 1}]
     ]
]
```

just returns the integral in symbolic form:

[image]

(Apologies for the large image - can't find the code that makes it a better size in the guides.)

Is this a sign that the integral is not calculable, or is it something in my instructions to Mathematica?

Comment: What is `term2j1`?

Comment: Oops - a hangover from a previous attempt! It's the term inside the output integral form. Corrected now :-)

Comment: One thing to try is to set values of $\alpha$ and $n$ with $k=1,\ldots,n$ and look for patterns.  With $\alpha=1$ you'll find the integral to be $\frac{1}{2} k \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 n}{4 k^2 n^2-4 k n^2+1}\right)$.  And finding patterns for $\alpha>1$ will, of course, become more difficult.  Setting specific values for the parameters seems to always give an explicit result.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll try that (tomorrow, now) and report back.

Comment: I think the `(n-n*u)` in that denominator will preclude a symbolic result. This simpler variant can be done for example: `Integrate[(k*u^(-1 + alf))/(1 + c*(n*u)^(2*alf)), {u, k, k + 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {1 <= k <= n, k >= 1, n >= 2, alf >= 1, c >= 4}]`

Comment: I think you're probably right @Daniel. But I'll leave it open for now in case some incredible mathematical genius just happens by! And, following up on @JimB's point, I'm working on it! It's easy for `\[Alpha]=1` but then we get into `SumRoot` results and it gets pretty hairy...